# not able to remove NoneTypes from list (python)

Tags: python, types, nonetype

i am trying to flatten a nested list into one list and removing all Nones. however when there is more than one None there is always one None remaining. also sometimes I have a None as an int type.. (as with the 2nd None in the first list li) what the heck?? haha. please help me out and thanks in advance.

```
#test lists--li is the orignal one provided by Button
li = [0, 2, [[2, 3], 8, 100, None, [[None]]], -2]
li1 = [-100, -100, [[[None,None]]]]
li2 = [[[[[None,None,1,2,3]]]], 6, 0, 0, 0]
li3 = [None, [None], 56, 78, None]
li4 = [[[[[None,1,2,3]]]], 6, 0, 0, 0]

#solution is theta(n) or more specifically O(n)
#which is the best case solution since we must
#loop the entire list

def flatten(li):
    i = 0
    while i < len(li):

        #only execute if the element is a list
        while isinstance(li[i], list):

        #taking the element at index i and sets it as the
        #i'th part of the list. so if l[i] contains a list
        #it is then unrolled or 'unlisted'

        li[i:i + 1] = li[i]

        i += 1

    #for li: for some reason the 2nd None at
    #index 7 is an int, probably because there
    #might've been an int at that index before manipulation?

    #for li1: the 2nd None or element at index 3
    #is of class 'NoneType' but the removal is not
    #occuring.. 

    for element in li:
        if element is None:
            li.remove(element)


    #conclusion: there is always one None remaining if
    #there is more than one None to begin with..
    return li

def main():
    flatten(li)
    print(li)
    flatten(li1)
    print(li1)
    flatten(li2)
    print(li2)
    flatten(li3)
    print(li3)
    flatten(li4)
    print(li4)

if __name__ == '__main__':
   main()
```

Comment: _None as an int type_ - what do you mean by this?

Comment: Don't try and remove items from a list while iterating over it. It's much easier to build a new list that contains only the items you want.

Comment: thanks so much roganjosh!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a recursive generator solution

```
def flatten(l):
   for i in l:
       if i is None:
           continue
       elif isinstance(i, list):
           for ii in flatten(i):
               yield ii
       else:
           yield i
```

You can convert its output to list if you want a list `list(flatten(li))`